# Codeigniter: How do I add a column with checkboxes for multiple select and delete using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I am having an issue where in I need checkboxes to delete multiple candidates rather than deleting them individually. I am using codeigniter and datatables(jQuery)

```
    <?php echo $this->table->generate(); ?>
```

That is how it loads in the view. Below I will place my controller:

```
    public function index ()
    {
        // Fetch all users
        // $this->data['tasks'] = $this->task_m->get();
        //datatable
        $tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table id="big_table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="table ">' );
        $this->table->set_template($tmpl); 
        $this->table->set_heading('Select','Client Name','Subject','Booking Date','Status','Actions');

        // Load view
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/task/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
```

And below is my model:

```
    public function list_tasks(){
    $userID = $this->session->userdata('id');

   $this->datatables->select("ci_customer.firstname,ci_task.subject_desc, ( DATE_FORMAT ( ci_task.booking_date ,('%d/%m/%Y
    '))), IFNULL( ( select c.pinged_status from ci_task_revisions c where c.task_id = ci_task.task_id order by revision_id desc limit 1 ), (ci_task.status) ) as status, ci_task.task_id,(CASE WHEN Date(ci_task.due_date) < CURDATE() AND ci_task.status <>'COMPLETE' THEN 'overdue' WHEN ci_task.assigner_id=ci_task.assignee_id THEN 'self' WHEN ci_task.assigner_id =$userID THEN 'assignee'  WHEN ci_task.assignee_id =$userID THEN 'assigner'  ELSE 'default'  END ) as type, ci_task.read")
    ->join('ci_customer','ci_customer.customer_id = ci_task.customer_id');


    $where = 'ci_task.assigner_id ='.$userID.' OR ci_task.assignee_id ='.$userID.'';
    $this->datatables->where($where);

    $this->datatables->edit_column('ci_task.task_id', btn_edit('admin/task/edit/' . '$1').' '.btn_sms('admin/task/sendSMS/' . '$1').' '.($this->session->userdata('role')?btn_delete('admin/task/delete/' .  '$1'):'')  ,'ci_task.task_id')
    ->from($this->_table_name);
    return $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery datatables has this functionality built in if you are just wanting to know how to display the checkboxes. You will need to add:

```
<input name="select_all" value="1" type="checkbox">
```

You can check out this example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/abhbs4x8/

Comment: I can input it in the set_heading function...  <?php echo $this->table->generate(); ?> but how do i add it in the view like so?

Answer (score 0):

Use the square brackets in input name.

```
<input name="candidates[]" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input name="candidates[]" value="2" type="checkbox">
...
```